# Simple way to print binary numbers in groups of nibbles

Tags: python, python-3.x

To improve readability, I would like to print a binary number in groups of 4 (nibbles), that are separated by an underscore.

For example:

```
9     => "1001"
60    => "0011_1100"
100   => "0110_0100"
63000 => "1111_0110_0001_1000"
```

I was wondering if there was perhaps a simple way of doing this?

Comment: By what logic `100` turns into `0011_0011`? If you want LE order of 4-bit sized _nibbles_, as it seems from your other examples, shouldn't it be `0100_0110`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have updated the example.

Comment: You now switched your examples from LE to BE order, can you first agree with yourself on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I made a mistake. It needs to be from left to right, highest nibble first, to lowest nibble last.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Splitting the logic into generating groups of 4 and joining.

```
def gen(x):
    while x:
        yield bin(x % 16)[2:].zfill(4)
        x >>= 4


def nibble(x):
    return "_".join(gen(x))
```

Comment: Can you reverse the nibble order to have the most-significant nibble on the left?

Comment: sure, e.g. `'_'.join(list(gen(x))[::-1])`.

Comment: What's the logic behind `x % 16` in the call to `bin` function?

Comment: In binary, 16 is 10000. So `x % 16` takes the last four digits in the binary expansion for `x`, possibly missing some leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def bin_nibble(val):
    b = bin(val)[2:]
    new_b =  '_'.join([b[::-1][i:i+4][::-1] for i in range(0, len(b), 4)][::-1])
```

If you want to add leading zeros:

```
def bin_nibble(val):
    b = bin(val)[2:]
    new_b = '_'.join([b[::-1][i:i+4][::-1] for i in range(0, len(b), 4)][::-1])
    return ''.join(['0']*(4 - len(b) % 4 if len(b) % 4 != 0 else 0) + [new_b])
```

Comment: It needs to have leading zeros on the highest nibble.

Answer (score 1):

Highest to lowest:

```
def binNibble(num):
    nibb = bin(num)[2:]
    k = 0 if len(nibb)%4 == 0 else 4-len(nibb)%4  # needs zeros?
    nibb = "0"*k + nibb                           # add them here
    return '_'.join(nibb[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(nibb),4) ) # put _ in


for i in range(0,1152,127):
    print(i,":  ",binNibble(i))
```

Output:

```
   0 :   0000
 127 :   0111_1111
 254 :   1111_1110
 381 :   0001_0111_1101
 508 :   0001_1111_1100
 635 :   0010_0111_1011
 762 :   0010_1111_1010
 889 :   0011_0111_1001
1016 :   0011_1111_1000
1143 :   0100_0111_0111
```

Your examples:

```
    9 :   1001
   60 :   0011_1100
  100 :   0110_0100
63000 :   1111_0110_0001_1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest way is with format (or f-strings which use format).

```
>>> format(63000, '019_b')
'1111_0110_0001_1000'
```

the `019_b` means 0-padded, 19-char, "_" nibble separated, binary

If you want the fewest number of nibbles, you may need to do a bit of math to replace the 19 in the formatting or add more padding and string replace any `0000_` with empty string.

E.g. using `039_b` for any 32-bit numbers. For 64-bit you would use `079_b` and so on.

```
>>> format(100, '039_b').replace('0000_', '')
'0110_0100
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this function:

```
import math
def bin_nibble(val):
    num_bits = len(format(val, "b"))
    return "_".join(reversed([format((val>>shift*4)&0x0F, "04b") 
        for shift in range(math.ceil(num_bits/4))]))
```

Comment: No, sorry about that. I forgot to add the `reversed()` statement. Please try the updated answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `str.format`:

```
def bin_nibble(a, pad=4):
    b = '{:b}'.format(a)
    if len(b) % pad:
        b = '0' * (pad - (len(b) % pad)) + b
    return '_'.join(b[k:k+pad] for k in range(0, len(b), pad))

tests = [9, 60, 100, 63000]
for k in tests:
    print(bin_nibble(k))
```

Output:

```
1001
0011_1100
0110_0100
1111_0110_0001_1000
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Tjaart**, based on your inputs and expected outputs, the following code will work as expected.

> Please try it and let me know if it fails for any of your input.

```
"""
INPUTS AND EXPECTED OUTPUTS:-

    9     => "1001"
    60    => "0011_1100"
    100   => "0110_0100"
    63000 => "1111_0110_0001_1000"
"""
def get_binary(n):
    s = bin(n)[2:]; # Getting binary string

    strs = [];

    while s:
        l = len(s);     # Finding lenght of binary string

        if l > 4:
            strs.insert(0, s[l-4:]);
            s = s[:l-4];
        else:
            l = len(s);
            s = "0"*(4-l) + s;  # If length is not equal to 4 (modify it by adding 0s to front)
            strs.insert(0, s);
            s = "";

    return "_".join(strs);

# EXAMPLE 1
a = 9;
print(get_binary(a)); # 1001

# EXAMPLE 2
b = 60;
print(get_binary(b)); # 0011_1100

# EXAMPLE 3
c = 100;
print(get_binary(c)); # 0110_0100

# EXAMPLE 4
d = 63000;
print(get_binary(d)); # 1111_0110_0001_1000
```